# How can I download LaTeX, PGF, TikZ, and get them to work?

Tags: tikz-pgf

The most I have ever done with software is clicking the download button for something like Adobe and then clicking through the installer. I am way over my head here. I am trying to download and use PGF and Ti*k*Z on my Windows 10 system, and I've followed instructions to download MiKTeX console and added PGF, Ti*k*Z, and `xcolor` to the root directory. I can use MiKTeX fine, but I don't know how to create diagrams. Please advise, and please use instructions that a dim-witted five-year-old could follow.  This is not my forte.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Didn't you download at least MiKTeX  basic installer?

Comment: welcome to tex.se! packages should be add to other package by use of "package" utility in MikTeX console. with this file name base will be automatically updated. in MikTeX root should be only path to your MikTeX directory and to your localtexmf.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. I don't want to discourage you, but you will have a very very hard time creating diagrams without reading and understanding some basic material.

Comment: No discouragement here, Johannes_B.  What material would you suggest?

Comment: @Matt https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/